# Android System shows toast message of "password may be incorrect"

Tags: android-11, toast-notifications

Recently I noticed there is a toast message popping up saying "password may be incorrect". With the help of toast source, I able to identify the source of the toast message which is Android System. What happen to my phone?

Oneplus 7T, Android 11

Comment: I AOSP source code there are some strings that contain this error message. They seem to be related to Wifi connection. May be this toast means that some known Wifi access point is near but the Wifi passphrase seem to be incorrect. Try to disable Wifi and check if that stops those messages.

Comment: thanks. it could be the potential reason. the message only pop up occasionally. let me try and see.